# Crispy forms self user

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I am using Django 1.4 and crispy forms.
There is some issue with that. I am looking at examples but still can`t figure it out.
I have example with "pk" arg where you edit requested user.
But now i need to make self editing. To edit my own data.

I got error like -

```
Failed lookup for key [form] in u ....
```

There is a long, long output.
My form has been builded because i put that form to other view and it works fine.

Here is my view

```
class ManagerProfileEditView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
model = User
template_name = 'profile/edit.html'
form_class = ProfileEditForm

def get_success_url(self):
    messages.success(self.request, _('Profile was edited'))
    return reverse('manager:profile_edit')
```

And here form

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    field = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

helper = FormHelper()
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ProfileEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
        Field('email', 'first_name', 'last_name',
            FormActions(
                Submit('save_changes', _('Save changes'), css_class="btn btn-primary"),
                Submit('cancel', _('Cancel')),
            )
        )
    )
```

As far as i understand prolly there should put which user i am going to "manage" ( which is like "self.user" )

I hope you understand my problem

p.s. Output in template is

```
{% crispy form %}
```